# Exponential Computation by Approximation in Linux Kernel's source code

Tags: c, math, linux-kernel, exponential, approximation

I have to modify a little bit of TCP algorithm in Linux Kernel's source code.
In it, I have to compute Congestion Window as following:

```
cwnd = cwnd (1-x^alpha)     where alpha and x are float type and satisfy 0<x<1, alpha >0.
```

Normally, one has to use #include Math.h and pow() function, right?

But I don't know if exponential computation can make operations slower.

So, I think of Bernoulli's inequality

```
(1-a)^x < 1-ax          where 0<a<1
```

So in my case, am I allowed to approximate the computation by using Bernoulli's.

```
x^alpha = (1-(1-x))^alpha ~ 1 - alpha(1-x)
```

If this is not OK then is there any way out.
Please help me with that.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask yourself what is the consequence of the worst case approximation error?  Are you sure someone hasn't already solved this problem?

Comment: Also, floating point in the kernel is generally *very strongly* discouraged... Banned, even...

Comment: ...and for good reason. Switching into kernel mode does not save the floating-point state of the program (that would make kernel-mode switches even more expensive...).

Comment: Do `alpha` and `x` ever change?

Comment: alpha and x always change. I do maths for some examples of alpha, x and see that if 0<x,alpha<1, the results are approximately true.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the question of using or not using floating point numbers in kernel mode, the approximation is not that stellar since it does not preserve positivity. For that use

```
x^a = 1/(1/x)^a = 1/(1+u)^a approx 1/(1+a*u)
```

where 1/x is greater or equal 1 and thus all terms in the approximation positive. Reinserting u=1/x-1 gives

```
x^a approx x/(x+a*(1-x))
```

which is 0 for x=0, 1 for x=1 and monotonically increasing in between. If x=p/q is rational and a integer, the resulting rational expression is

```
p/(p+a*(q-p)).
```

Comment: 0.2^0.5 = 0.447 but if following above approximation, 0.2^0.5~0.333 and not very close to original result. I thought the approximation is not stellar in case of small value of x.

Comment: It is better for a>1. Finding good approximations for a<1 is difficult because of the infinite slope at x=0. Usually, approximating functions have finite slope everywhere.